# Fetch number from and String List from firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch field values in my app and  access  values from firebase Here's how DB looks like

[image: Here is how my database looks like]

```
  private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    static List<String> categoryist =new ArrayList<>(  );
    
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_categories );
    
            firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            loadData();
    }
    
    
    loadData(){
    
    private void loadData() {
    
            categoryist.clear();
    
            firestore.collection( "Online Class" ).document("Subjects")
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
    
                        if(doc.exists()){

 /*Here i also tried to use int and long data type but it is still giving same error with nul pointer Exception*/


                            Integer count = new Integer( (Integer) doc.get("No_of_subjects") );
                            for (int i = 1; i<=count;i++){
                                String subjectName = doc.getString( "Subject "+String.valueOf( i ) );
                                categoryist.add( subjectName );
                            }
    
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText( CategoriesActivity.this,"No Subject Exists" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
    
                    }else {
    
                        Toast.makeText( CategoriesActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                }
            } );
    
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

Here I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try to cast as a Long variable ? If I am not wrong firebase number data stored as long.

Comment: yes I did try it using long and also int